# Inability to install Vuze using .tar.bz2 file

Tags: vuze

Problem: Inability to install Vuze torrent client using VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2. (https://www.vuze.com/)

What did an author do:

FIRST STEP - 0. Downloaded the file (obviously!)

NEXT STEP - 1. Extracted the file into specific directory

-Technically 2-4 steps can be avoided by simply opening the README.txt file in extracted folder, but it was done according
to the Askubuntu.com tutorial.-

NEXT STEP - 2. The work: Terminal -> cd 'directory'

Output: Navigated to the directory

NEXT STEP - 3. The work: Once in a directory - looked for a file named INSTALL/INSTALL.TXT/README

NEXT STEP - 4. The work: Terminal -> xdg-open README.txt

Output: the file got opened

NEXT STEP - 5. According to Askubuntu.com tutorial - This file will contain the right steps to follow to continue the installation process.

In this case the file gives the following output:

"REQUIREMENTS:
Azureus requires Sun Java 1.5.x or newer to run.
JRE 1.6 (6.0 series) is highly recommended.
http://java.sun.com

RUNNING:
1  Extract the contents of this .tar.bz2 file.
2. Change to the 'azureus' directory where the files were extracted.
3. Start Azureus by running the script named 'azureus'; ex. "./azureus"

NOTE:
If you have the Java JRE installed somewhere unusual (or not in your PATH),
use the JAVA_PROGRAM_DIR option in the script."

NEXT STEP - 6. Working according to readme.txt:

6.1 Extract the contents of this .tar.bz2 file.

The work: well, the directory I am in is already the one resulting from extracting
the .tar.bz2 file. Perhaps the tutorial refers to the azureus2.jar file?

Output: extracted file and folder name changed to Azureus

6.2 Change to the 'azureus' directory where the files were extracted.

The work: Terminal -> cd Azureus

Output: changed directory

6.3 Start Azureus by running the script named 'azureus'; ex. "./azureus"

The work: Terminal -> azureus'; ex. "./azureus

Output: '>  ' (empty line, pending, doesnt do anything)

Conclusion: following the tutorial didnt work in my case.

NEXT STEP - 7. According to Askubuntu.com tutorial - there is also another way of installing, called classic approach, which I checked.
The classic approach: extract the file -> cd dir_name -> ./configure -> make -> sudo make install or checkinstall

The work: Terminal -> cd Vuze

Output: changed doirectory

The work: Terminal -> ./configure

Output: bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

The work: Terminal -> make

Output: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

The work: Terminal -> sudo make install

Output: make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

The work: Terminal -> checkinstall

Output: make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.

...
Conclusion: using the classic approach did not work in my case.

Question:

1. If both the classic approach and the readme.txt file approach do not work - author is desperately looking for assistance.

Best Regards!

Comment: In Step 6.3, it sounds like you typed `"./azureus` literally (including the leading unbalanced `"`). It should be just `./azureus`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Assuming the VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2 file was downloaded at ~/Downloads

Open a terminal.

Run into it.

tar -xjvf VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2

cd vuze

./vuze